# Как применить фильтр к результату {% url ... %}?

Tags: django, шаблоны

Можно ли применить фильтр, в частности `|cut` к результату вывода `{% url 'name' %}`?

Я пробовал

```
{% url 'get_dialog'|cut:"/" %}
```

Но безрезультатно. "/" никуда не делся. Так же пытался засунуть результат {% url 'get_dialog' %} в переменную, но рендер меня в принципе не понял:

> 'with' expected at least one variable assignment

В общем возможно ли это?

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Почему бы вам не стереть слэши в urls.py вместо вот этого вот?

Answer (score 1):

В джанге есть способ получить url, не отображая:

```
{% url 'name' arg2 as the_url %}
```

И дальше работать с ним как с обычными переменными, применяя фильтры:

```
name= {{ the_url|cut:"/" }}
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: да, это работает